# jQuery: get destination and content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some array, received from similar "a" elements.

```
links = jQuery('a');
```

How can I get string with href destination and content? Something like:

```
<a href="/dest1">First</a>
<a href="/dest2">Second</a>
need =>
/dest1 First, /dest2 Second
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at jquery's attr and html functions. And at the href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `join()`:

```
$('a').map(function(index, link) {
    return link.href + ' ' + $(link).text();
 // return [link.href, $(link).text()].join(' ');  // This works too
}).get().join(', ');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4nr5/**

- `.map()` iterates over your matched elements;
- `return` replaces the element with the string that you returned (in the object).
- `.get()` converts the returned jQuery object into the underlying JS object, which is an array in this case.
- `.join()` joins the parts together.

Comment: Ah, like your answer better. I was wondering what the best way to convert a jQuery object into an array was.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a little jsFiddle demonstrating how you would do this, you can view it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tUY5K/

This is the method that does the work:

```javascript
function anathem() {
  var links = $('a');
  var anathemString = "";
  links.each(function (index) {
    anathemString += $(this).attr('href') + " " + $(this).html();
    if (index != links.length - 1) {
      anathemString += ", ";
    }
  });
  return anathemString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting first the link and content;

```
var first_link = $('a:eq(0)').attr('href'); //first link
var first_content_text = $('a:eq(0)').text(); //content of first anchor element
var first_content_html = $('a:eq(0)').html(); //content of first anchor element including markup
```

For getting the second link and content:

```
var second_link = $('a:eq(1)').attr('href'); //second link
var second_content_text = $('a:eq(1)').text(); //content of second anchor element
var second_content_html = $('a:eq(1)').html(); //content of second anchor element including markup
```

Various techniques:

**":eq" psuedo-class**

```
$('a:eq(0)'); //this gets the first anchor. (":nth-child" pseudo-class is "0-indexed", meaning it starts counting from 0)
```

**":nth-child" psuedo-class**

```
$("a:nth-child(1)"); //this also gets the first anchor. (":nth-child" pseudo-class is "1-indexed", meaning it starts counting from 1)
```

**.first() and .next() methods**

```
$("a").first(); //gets the first anchor element
$("a").first().next(); //gets the second anchor element
```

**Getting the underlying DOM element**

```
$('a').get(0); //This gets the first element in the anchor node list
$('a')[0]; //This also does the same but cannot specify a negative index
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of links :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var hrefs_array = $.map($('a'), function(el) { return [$(el).attr("href"), $(el).text()];})
```

Or something like this

```
    var hrefs_array = [];
    $('a').each(function(index, el){
                     hrefs_array.push([$(el).attr("href"), $(el).text()]);
                });
```